# Xamarin in Visual Studio File import to Solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, file-io, xamarin.forms

I Try to Open a file within Xamarin.
I followed this tutorial:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/files/#Loading_and_Saving_Files

The File that i wand to open seems to not exist.

It opens the path "/data/user/0/SQL2.Android/files"

I tried all different properties on the file. 
I don't know if the file I want to open is in the Solution. It should be.

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is not making any sense to me. Please describe what file you are trying to find and what is the code you are using. Not all files in the solution are copied to the filesystem of your device, so you can't assume that you can find the file there.

Comment: I want to put a  Zip file and a xml into my solution.

"/data/user/0/SQL2.Android/files"
Is the path I get from the Dependency Service.
I just want to know how I can configure Visual studio so I can put files into this folder.

My Phone isn't rooted and my notebook is to slow to run the emulator.